# In MVC3 is it possible to have multiple EditorTemplates for the same type?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have some DateTime fields on my MVC model classes - some which require a Date as input and others that require a Time as input - but both are DateTime properties.

Is it possible to have an EditorTemplate for DateTime that somehow produces a date picker to properties that are meant to be dates, and a time picker for properties that are meant to be times?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, here is one way:

In `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` (or `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates`, create template files that use your favourite view engine (example uses Razor/C#)

file Date.cshtml

```
replace this with a real date picker
```

file Time.cshtml

```
replace this with a real time picker
```

Then, in your model:

```cs
[UIHint("Date")]
public DateTime DateProperty { get; set; }

[UIHint("Time")]
public DateTime TimeProperty { get; set; }
```

The [`UIHint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute.aspx) attribute name has to match the file name of your template, and `UIHint` is in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`, so you will need the appropriate using statement/assembly reference if you don't have it already.

Alternatively, use a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) to represent your times - that is what `DateTime` returns for its `TimeOfDay` property...